# Subnets in Server OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, vpn, openvpn, ufw

I have set up an openvpn server according to my needs: I need to have 256 subnets and for each subnet I need 256 users, so I  thought about creating a server of type 10.8.0.0/16. The server runs on ubuntu server 18.04 and the version of iptables is 1.6.0.

These are my goals:

- each host must be able to see the hosts of the same subnet (done);
- each subnet must be isolated (done);
- Hosts of subnet 10.8.1.0 must be able to reach hosts of any other subnet (missing)

For the test I have two subnets: 10.8.0.0 and 10.8.1.0, I have ufw disabled and I tried with the following command:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -s 10.8.1.0/16 -d 10.8.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
```

But anyway from the 10.8.1.0 subnet I can't reach the 10.8.0.0 subnet. I think I am doing something wrong with the subnets,network masks or with the iptables commands, but I don't understand what. Can someone help me?

Here is the server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
topology subnet
ca  /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert  /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key  /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh  /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir ccd
client-to-client
keepalive 10 600
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

Each user will have a file in the ccd folder which will specify the mask and IP address, below is an example of client1:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.55 255.255.255.0
```

Now I have created a new certificate called client2, which will have the following information:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.1.4 255.255.255.0
```

The client1 connects and gets the address 10.8.0.55, the client2 connects and gets the address 10.8.1.4.
How can I get access to the 10.8.0.0 subnet?
I hope I have been clear in describing the problem

- UPDATED 14/04/2021 -

[openvpn-status.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWOxF.png)

[tracert windows after connected via VPN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riwhK.png)

Comment: Interestingly enough, you specified a `255.255.0.0` mask in the `server` directive, but push `255.255.255.0` to the clients. I can't predict which routes be where without trying this. Please do the following: connect both clients to the VPN, and when the `openvpn-status.log` file is updated, show us a contents of that file (you can mask out non-VPN addresses) and an output of `ip route` (a routing table) on both clients?

Comment: I also work the same when specifying the mask to /24. I have updated the post with the additional information

Comment: A `/16` prefix is too large to accommodate your requirements. The `/24` (`255.255.255.0`)  can only have 254 users (253 not counting the gateway), but you need 256 users, so you need to use `/23` (`255.255.254.0`) that has 510 usable addresses.

Comment: I don't care much about hosts, my interest is in managing multiple vpn networks:
10.8.0.0
10.8.1.0
10.8.2.0
....